# UWP. How find already paired devices but which now in discoverable mode?

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth, pairing

Is it possible to find device, that already paired (but not connected) but in discoverable mode now? I would like to make it by standard UWP possibilities. Maybe I need some specific aqsFilter for DeviceWatcher or something else?

**UPDATED**

Seems, like I found solution to use System.Devices.Aep.IsPresent when create DeviceWatcher, but It looks strange, because this property always sets true even for devices, that paired, but offline =(

Comment: There is no easy way to do that. You have to enumerate paired devies first. Tnen for eash device you have to check if the device is available. However, it requires call to DeviceIoControl() function.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I found System.Devices.Aep.IsPresent, and from description of this property sounds like it exactly what I want, but unfortunately this property sets true always even for devices, that paired, but offline

Comment: There is no way to know if device is really available for paired,devices. Except one way: Connect to device somehow. You can find anything in docs. But belive me (I'm past 13 years with Bluetooth) - no way to do so on Window splatform with Microsoft Bluetooth drivers. Thatr is so starting from Windows XP SP 3. Probably one day they add something, but for now - no way. Some trick can be found there [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45568345/windows-uwp-bluetooth-app-devices-showing-up-when-scanning-even-when-they-are-p?rq=1) but that does not solve the problem at all.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Sorry, but maybe you don't really understand what I need? I don't need to know is device really available for pairing. I need to know is already paired device (but not connected) now in discoverable mode. So, I need to understand, if I found already paired, online, but not connected device, that try to find pairing or it just offline device. It need me to understand which paired device I need to unpair and "pair" again.

Comment: So, I have two type of paired devices: 
1) That was paired to other computer, but paired status saved in this computer and now I would like to pair this "broken" device again and I need to upair and pair it again.
2) Just offline device that has real pair with me.
And in general it possible to solve. I've tried to use 32feet library and it has property "discoverableModeOnly" when you find devices. But I decide to not using this lib because it has other unsolving problems to use.

Comment: P.S. I've tried solution by your link and unfortunately it doesn't work, because property IsConnectable always sets in true too.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko and sorry for offtop maybe, but can we talk personaly somewhere (discord for ex. or somewhere else?)

Comment: You are mixing up different things. Any way, ping me by Skype and we can discuss it. Skype ID is: mike.petrichenko