# Detecting bluetooth signal strength from RSSI on Windows

Tags: c#, c++, windows, bluetooth, rssi

I'm trying to understand how I might access the RSSI of a Bluetooth (not LE) connection in either C# or C++ on Windows.

My understanding is that there is no straightforward "GetRSSI()" type command but is there any indirect way to access it?

Everything I've found so far seems to be aimed at LE connections.

Edit:
I've had a look into AEPs and tried to get the SignalStrength AEP from a connected BT device.

```
    foreach (var key in deviceInformation.Properties.Keys)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{key}: {deviceInformation.Properties.GetValueOrDefault(key)}");
    }
```

Gives:

```
System.ItemNameDisplay: <ommitted>

System.Devices.DeviceInstanceId: 
System.Devices.Icon: C:\Windows\System32\DDORes.dll,-2001
System.Devices.GlyphIcon: C:\Windows\System32\DDORes.dll,-3001
System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled: 
System.Devices.IsDefault: 
System.Devices.PhysicalDeviceLocation: 
System.Devices.ContainerId:
```

With the item name omitted by me.

So it looks like there are no AEPs, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: There is a way to get RSSI for Classic Bluetooth device on Windows 10 platform with WinRT API. However, device must be connected anyhow. So look on WinRT API or use thrid party library.

Comment: Do you have any specific examples? I can find the BluetoothSignalStrengthFilter class in the api but I can't see any explanation of how it's used, other than as part of the BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher class

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any code I can share because it is part of our commercial product. However you can google for this string "System.Devices.Aep.SignalStrength". It should give you some ideas.

Comment: I've done some research and I don't seem to have any AEPs listed for my connected Bluetooth device - would you be able to take a look at my edit above?  @MikePetrichenko

Comment: It's not a key, it's a property of DeviceInformation.

Comment: How do I access it though? The DeviceInformation properties seem to be stored in a Dictionary, so surely it would have a corresponding key?

Comment: You should use the "Property" property (or get_Property method in case of C++).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "Property" property. There is no property (static or otherwise) on the DeviceInformation class called "Property". 

Reading the MSDN documentation:
"A DeviceInformation object has some basic properties, such as Id and Kind, but most of the properties are stored in a property bag under Properties."

Comment: Use CreateFromIdAsync(String, IIterable<String>) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.createfromidasync) Then call DeviceInformation.Properties (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.properties). That is why we ask money for our product. Unfortunately that is all I can share with you.

Comment: Do not forget that device must be connected! No way to get RSSI from not connected device.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but I just started a new project where I also want information about the SignalStrength for Bluetooth (not LE) devices.

@Mike-Petrichenko was giving you some good hints. After following his advice of searching for "System.Devices.Aep.SignalStrength" I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45568345).

After going through the OP's Code and debugging a little, I came up with this solution:

```
private const string SignalStrengthProperty = "System.Devices.Aep.SignalStrength";
```

```
var additionalProperties = new[] { SignalStrengthProperty };

DeviceWatcher mWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector(), additionalProperties);
```

```
var rssi = Convert.ToInt16(deviceInformation.Properties[SignalStrengthProperty]);
```